# LibGDX gives a gradle error when I try and build my game

Tags: java, gradle, compiler-errors, libgdx

Im trying to build my LibGDX game with the command

```
./gradlew desktop:dist
```

but it keeps giving this error

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :core:compileJava
Note: E:\Programming\Java\LIBGdx\TextGame\core\src\com\imjustdoom\textgame\stage\PlayGame.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :desktop:dist FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':desktop:dist'.
> Cannot expand ZIP 'E:\Programming\Java\LIBGdx\TextGame\core\build\libs\core-1.0.jar' as it does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
5 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

I am using intelliJ and Java 11 if that matters

I have tried running ./gradlew clean but that didnt help

Im trying to build for desktop

Answer (score 0):

What plugin do you use?

I mean from which plugin does `dist` task come from? Or is this a custom task?

`compileJava` task won't produce any artifact like **jar** file for you, it will only generate class files.

First you have to execute `gradlew build` that contains `assebmle` task or `gradlew assebmle` directly so that jar will be generated in `build\libs\` and only after that run `gradlew desktop:dist`

It's also a question how projects are structured. I see compilation is done on **core** project, then `dist` is failing on **desktop** one, maybe here there is another issue.

Comment: i just created a LibGDX project from their project generator then imported it with intellij. The project looks like this https://imgur.com/a/Dk8n3d6.

also ./gradlew desktop:dist runs the compileJava command.

gradle.build files


Main one: https://bin.birdflop.com/geqopisana.php  
Desktop: https://bin.birdflop.com/numukofiza.typescript  
Core: https://bin.birdflop.com/keyeyagucu.csharp

Answer (score 0):

So the answer seemed to be downgrading gradlew to 6.7 using. Mustve defaulted to gradle 7 for some reason

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 6.7
```

Comment: I am running libGDX generated with gradle 7.0 without any issues. `gradlew :desktop:dist` is able to provide a jar.

Comment: weird, that was my fix though